# Access Firebase project configuration from github action

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, github-actions

I started to implement a nextjs app that I want to deploy to firebase using github action.

While developing localy i set up a .env file with the project configs which i retrieve with the following code

```
const config = {
    apiKey: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_API_KEY,
    authDomain: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
    projectId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
    storageBucket: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
    messagingSenderId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
    appId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_APP_ID
} as const;

...

const firebaseApp = initializeApp(config);

...
```

To use github action for firebase hosting deployment, I initiated the repo localy with the following command: `firebase init hosting:github` which generated a FIREBASE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT in the github secrets.
Now my questions are the following one:

- Should I add each of the config key as github secret, expose them through the CI and then retreive them as `process.env.xx` in the code ?
- Should I use the service account localy and while deploying ? (if yes how can i get the config values from the SA ?)
- Should I use a firebase token ?
- What are the best security practices regarding this topic ?

Huge thanks in advance!